# PHP: Unique pages per DB item or single php page with _GET?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm in the early stages of developing a site that will have a webpage for each database entry.  My question is - what are the pros and cons to having either (1) a single php page with a $_GET returning the specific database item or (2) individual webpages for each item?

For instance, example 1 would be like this -

- mysite.com/alphabet.php?letter=a
- mysite.com/alphabet.php?letter=b
- mysite.com/alphabet.php?letter=c

Example 2 would be -

- mysite.com/alphabet/letter_a.php
- mysite.com/alphabet/letter_b.php
- mysite.com/alphabet/letter_c.php

The only site I built heavily off of MySQL, I used example 1.  Given that the code to display these would function the same for each entry, I'd assume that example 1 would be the best practice, but when I go to similar sites, they seem to favor example 2.

I've tried to search this site as well as the web for this answer, but it seems to be an awkward search phrase, as I've returned empty handed.  Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Might be they've just been using url rewriting, though. An extension (.html, .php) or the lack of it doesn't mean anything

Comment: You can use example 1, and try url rewrite in .htaccess [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

Comment: Does the conversion work both ways?  Will it convert the canonical url to the one displayed, but then also allow a user to key in the displayed url to get to the canonical url?

Answer (score 0):

Actually both usages are old school for last years. Following formats used mainly:

- mysite.com/alphabet/letter/a
- mysite.com/alphabet/letter/b
- mysite.com/alphabet/letter/c

This format is called `friendly url` or `pretty url` and in most cases this points to `Alphabet` controller's `letter` action with one argument `a`,`b` or `c` which will be like:

```
Class AlphabetController {
  public function letter($letter) {
    $DbModel->getListStartingWith($letter);
  }
}
```

Comment: Or it's just an url rewriting for a simple $_GET parameter